# 2d city builder for gnu/linux?

Tags: linux, game

I'm looking for city building games for GNU/Linux that are with 2D graphics (I'm playing on my laptop which has low performance, and also I just like 2D graphics better personally)

I prefer if the game is not more than 10 years old. It's okay if it runs through wine

What can you recommend? Grateful for help!

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit)

Comment: Is false 3D (isometric perspective) OK? I guess you are ready to pay money, right?

Comment: Do you need multiplayer? Do you need the game to work offline?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Hi and thank you for the questions. Yes I like the good old isometric perspective. I don't need multiplayer, and offline play isn't important (but preferably yes)